# Combining PHP variables in a while loop

Tags: php, variables

Not sure if the Title is the correct title but I'm not sure how to call what I'm trying to accomplish. On the surface it looks fairly simple...

I wrote the following code:

```
$var1 = "55";
$var2 = "66";
$var3 = "22";
$var4 = "22";
$x = 1;
$result = "null";

while($x < 5) {
$result = "$" . "var" . "$x";
echo $result;
echo " | ";
$x = $x +1;
}
```

Was hoping to get:
55 | 66 | 22 |22

Instead I'm getting:
$var1 | $var2 | $var3 | $var4 |

I tried many things but unable to find a working solution, any help would be much approached.

Thank you

Comment: [Just use an array.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: you are building a string called `$var1` when you mean to evaluate that string to the value of `$var1`. I guess you don't know what variable names you will handle beforehand. However, using `eval` on an unknown input stream is a bad approach. Use arrays and iterate over them as @PeeHaa said.

Comment: Array is a  great idea but in this case I really would like to find a way to make it work without an array. The code above is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do which does contain four different arrays. I figured it would be easier to post this strip down code that emulate the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this statement here,

```
$result = "$" . "var" . "$x";
```

`$result` variable is actually a string. To get it's value, use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Also, with your approach you'll end up getting an extra `|` at the end. So to achieve your desired result, change your `while()` loop in the following way,

```
while (true) { 
    $result = "var" . $x; 
    echo $$result;
    if($x++ == 4) break;
    echo " | ";
}
```

Here's a [**demo**](https://eval.in/702376)

---

Furthermore, do look into **@freginold**'s solution as well, which I slightly modified to suit your needs. Initialize `$x` with `5` and change your `while()` loop in the following way,

```
$output = "";
while (--$x) { 
    $result = "var" . $x; 
    $output = $$result . " | " . $output; 
}
echo rtrim($output, " | ");
```

In this solution, while coming out of the loop you'll end up getting an extra `|` at the end, which you need to trim down using [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) function.

Here's a [**demo**](https://eval.in/702377)

Comment: This is the best solution so far.  You could even condense your code further by including `$output="";` in your initializations and then changing your `while` loop to this:    `while (--$x) {
  $result = "var" . "$x";
  $output = $$result . " | " . $output;
}`    with `echo $output;` at the end.

Comment: @freginold Good attempt,;-) but there's one flaw in your code, which I noticed now. In your method the elements will be printed in reverse order, given that we initialize `$x` with `5`.

Comment: Of course you would also have to change `$x = 1;` to `$x = 5;`

Comment: they are processed in reverse order, but printed in correct order, via adding the new values to the beginning of the output string :)

Comment: @freginold Ah, you're right, I didn't think it through. Nice solution! I'll add it in my answer as well. Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without a `while` loop:

```
$var1 = "55";
$var2 = "66";
$var3 = "22";
$var4 = "22";

$vars = array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4);
echo implode(' | ', $vars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would an array work better?

```
<?php 

  $vars = array( 
    'var1' => 55, 
    'var2' => 66, 
    'var3' => 22, 
    'var4' => 22
    'x'    => 1
  );

  foreach($vars as $key => $value){
    print $value;
  }

?>
```